# Inject variable inside HTML element not inner html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to inject a string inside an HTML tag

```
<td anyElement="{{myString}}" >some random text here </td>
```

I want it to be interpreted like this

```
<td anyElement='Some string'>some random text here </td>
```

but it does not get interpreted and stays

```
<td anyElement={{myString}}>some random text here </td>
```

in my controller I have declared

```
$scope.myString="'Some string'";
```

but it gets interpreted when I put it between it, like this

```
<td> {{myString}} </td>
```

into this

```
<td> 'Some string' </td>
```

Comment: `element.outerHTML = element.outerHTML.replace("{{yourString}}", "some string")`

Comment: That's not what I want. If I wanted that I would just write it manually. But the string is built inside the controller from a data coming from the server

Comment: Then rephrase your question.

Comment: Have you tried to put it between double quotes?
`anyElement="{{myVar}}"`

Comment: Yes @Aenandon I hve tried doing that and it does not work

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want an attribute's value to be set by a variable declared in your controller.

To do that, you need to include double quotes around the curly braces like this:

```
<td anyElement="{{myString}}">some random text here </td>
```

Edit:

Right-click inspect on the text in this Plunkr to see the result: https://embed.plnkr.co/Za54w7/

Comment: I edited my answer with a plunkr demonstrating that it does indeed work. Do check it out.